# "Too much recursion" error when using intanceof over typeof?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, recursion, loops, scriptmanager

I was making a function to convert all dates in an object to strings and when I used the following function I got a error in FF  "too much recursion". (It also fails in IE and chrome)

```
    function datesToString(obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Object) {
            if (obj instanceof Date) {
                obj = "this part does not matter";
            } else {
                for (var key in obj) { obj[key] = datesToString(obj[key]); }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

but when I changed it to use typeof it worked fine?

```
    function datesToString(obj) {
        if (obj  && typeof obj == "object") {
            if (obj instanceof Date) {
                obj = "this part does not matter";
            } else {
                for (var key in obj) { obj[key] = datesToString(obj[key]); }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

It should be the same amount of recursion. Am I missing something? Why am I getting an error with the first example but not the second?

Update: 
here is an example of the object I was using (in json form)

```
Contact = {
    "LContactID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "CellPhone": "",
    "HomePhone": "4564564560",
    "OtherPhone": "",
    "BirthDate": new Date(-62135575200000),
    "SSN": "456456456",
    "HowToContact": 1,
    "ContactType": 3,
    "Address1": "123 test",
    "Address2": "apt. 1",
    "City": "Valparaiso",
    "State": "IN",
    "Zip": "46383",
    "FullAddress": "123 test, apt. 1",
    "BuilderID": "",
    "FullAddressWithCityState": "123 test\r\napt. 1\r\nValparaiso, IN 46383",
    "WorkHours": "9-5",
    "ContactTime": "",
    "ContactMethod": "???",
    "IsMilitaryOrSelfEmployed": false,
    "AlternateContactName": "",
    "AlternateContactPhone": "",
    "ContactID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "Password": null,
    "FirstName": "updatetest",
    "MiddleName": null,
    "LastName": "test_",
    "Suffix": null,
    "EmailAddress": null,
    "EmailAddressAlternate": null,
    "WorkPhone": "6546546540",
    "WorkPhoneExt": null,
    "CreatedOn": new Date(1263597309000),
    "CreatedOnOverride": new Date(-62135575200000),
    "ModifiedOn": new Date(1264014749000),
    "SCRep": "",
    "HBCRep": "",
    "PPPRep": "",
    "DPSRep": "",
    "DRSRep": "",
    "RDRep": "",
    "OwnerID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "FullName": "updatetest test_",
    "ImportID": 0,
    "IncludeEmail": false,
    "PreferredLanguage": 1,
    "CarbonCopyList": [],
    "HearAboutUs": 5,
    "HearAboutUsOther": "",
    "init": function() { },
    "update": function() { },
    "load": function() { }
}
```

It looks like when I remove the method parameters (init,update and load) it works with the instanceof example.

UPDATE: This is a ASP.Net ScriptManager problem it turns out. Sorry for not including the fact that I was working with an ASP.Net website.The ASP.Net ScriptManager prototypes methods to Function which causes an infinity loop when doing a recursive for in loop on a function.

Comment: If an `obj` is a `Date` object, what do you expect to find in `obj.d`?

Comment: I wrote it so you could send it an object that contains dates (where it changes all the dates in that object to strings and returns that object) or be able to just send a date (in which case it returns a date string)

Comment: Can you give us more info about these enigmatic obj.format and obj.d? They are not part of the standard Date object.

Also, when it "worked fine" did it really work? I mean, were all the dates changed to strings as you expected?

Comment: this is the actually code I am using the resulted in the error. I'm using asp.Net that prototypes a format function to the date object. That part is an arbitrary part of the problem. You can remove the line:
<cod>obj = typeof obj.format == 'function' ? obj.format("MM/dd/yyyy") : obj.d.toDateString();</code>
and still get the same error

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. If you really want the answer, you can save the HTML page, make it self-contained, trim it down to a reasonable size (and remove any sensitive information you don't want to share), and paste it here or someplace like pastehtml.com. Then folks can troubleshoot and help.

Comment: Not necessarily. By changing the prototype, you've actually added items to the hash, e.g. there's now an obj["d"] and an obj["format"]. Not sure that's causing your problem, but it might be related.

Comment: I figured it out. The ASP.Net ScriptManager prototypes methods to Function which causes an infinity loop when doing a recursive for in loop. Function inherits from Object so it passes the instanceof example. Functions were filtered out in the second example of course because typeof a function is "function"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(First, let me say that I tried your code on FF 3.5.7 and it didn't run into an infinite recursion. maybe you used a different input example?)

Anyway, to answer your questions:

(a) Why do you get an infinite recursion? Because an object may refer to itself. If `o.f==o` then calling your function on `o` will fire a subsequent call on `o.f` which is actually `o` and so on...

(b) Why the difference between the two versions? `obj instanceof Object` checks if obj is an instance of `Object` or an instance of a *subclass* thereof. Given that every Javascript object inherits from Object then this condition is trivially true, and is thus meaningless. Net result is that the first `if` always succeeds. On the other hand `typeof obj == "object"` checks that obj is an instance of Object. This may be false, for example, if `obj` is an instance of String (at which case `typeof obj` yields `String`). Hence, the difference.